# Master Theorem Question $T (n) = 3/2T (2n/3)+ n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I was solving Master Theorem examples, I came across following example

$(3/2)T(2n/3)+n$

I am confused about what will be value of $ a=3/2$?

What will be proposed recurrence solution?

Comment: is this $$T(n)=\frac{3}{2}T\left(\frac{2n}{3}\right)+n$$?

Comment: it is 3/2T and 2n/3

Comment: is it the right formula?

Comment: You were right, it is (3/2)T

Comment: it should $$T(n)=\frac{3 c_1 n}{2}+\frac{n \log (n)}{\log \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)}$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner you wrote exact notation in your first comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given, recurrence relation is:

$$T(n) = \frac{3}{2}T\left(\frac{2n}{3}\right) + n$$

Standard master recurrence relation is:

$$T(n) = a T\left(\frac{n}{b}\right) + n$$

Your given recurrence relation can be written as:

$$T(n) = \frac{3}{2}T\left(\frac{n}{3/2}\right) + n$$

So, $a = 3/2$ and $b = 3/2$. [Now apply Master Theorem Case $(2)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem#Case_2):

$$T(n) = \Theta(n.\log n)$$

Answer (score 0):

One of the cases of the Master's theorem says that if $T(n) = aT(n/b) + f(n)$ and $f(n) = \Theta(n^{\log_b a})$, then $T(n) = \Theta(n^{\log_b a} \log n)$.  In your example, $a=b=3/2$, and so $\log_b a = 1$. The condition $f(n) = \Theta(n^{\log_b a})$ is satisfied because $n = \Theta(n^1)$, and so the solution to the recurrence is $T(n) = \Theta(n^1 \log n) = \Theta(n \log n)$.